# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and id not increment

Tags: oracle11g

I want to copy my table without null value to another table and I want to specify my id auto_increment. But when I run the following I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO ETL_ACTVT 
SELECT * 
FROM DIM_ACTVT 
WHERE DESIGN_ACTVT is not null  
order by ID_DIM_ACTVT=1 ;
```

Comment: The `order by` is useless to begin with because rows are not stored sorted in a relational database. But more importantly `order by ID_DIM_ACTVT=1` is invalid. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: "I get an error" ... and that error is...?

Comment: because when i don't specify id begin with 1 i get id not increment in my new table after copy